# How to chain model managers?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two abstract models:

```
class SoftDeleteModel(models.Model):
    objects = SoftDeletableManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class BookAwareModel(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I use often use these models together for DRY purposes, e.g.:

```
class MyNewModel(SoftDeleteModel, BookAwareModel):
```

The `SoftDeleteModel` has a custom manager `SoftDeletableManager()`:

```
class SoftDeletableManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):

        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_removed=False)
```

If I want to extend the `BookAware` abstract model to add a queryset filter on `Books` whilst still preserving the `SoftDeletableManager()` how would I go about this?

E.g. I can't add `objects = BookManager()` to `BookAwareModel` because it will overwrite the `SoftDeletableManager`.

Comment: Would it be an option for you to define the Manager for ```BookAwareModel``` as a subclass of the ```SoftDeletableManager```?

Answer (score 1):

Having played with your code a bit I came up with three possible solutions which seem to work (according to my tests):

**Option 1**:

Create a combined manager which is used when defining your concrete MyNewModel and use it for that model:

```
class CombiManager(SoftDeletableManager, BookAwareManager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs1 = SoftDeletableManager.get_queryset(self)
        qs2 = BookAwareManager.get_queryset(self)
        return qs1.intersection(qs2)
```

and then

```
class MyNewModel(SoftDeleteModel, BookAwareModel):

    objects = CombiManager()
```

**Option 2:**

Create a Manager for the BookAware model as a subclass of the SoftDeleteableManager

```
class BookAwareManager(SoftDeletableManager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(your_filter)
```

and then add it to your `BookAware` model with a different name than 'objects':

```
class BookAwareModel(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    book_objects = BookAwareManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

allowing you to get the filtered queryset like

```
MyNewModel.book_objects.all()
```

**Option 3**

Put the BookAwareManager as in Option two as manager into your concrete MyNewModel. Then you can leave the managers name as the default 'objects'